# What is the best way to handle the view routing in Web API Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, razor, controller, routes

I have this doubt, because always when I create a Web API project I use the API controllers to get data and I create a normal controller where I define all my methods that returns ActionResult to redirect to the views and I am not sure if this is the best way.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web API is not for views. API stands for *application programming interface* - that is, there is no user interface (views) that a user can interact with.

There is another framework with view functionality built-in: [ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started). It will even run side-by-side within your Web API project - see [How to add MVC to existing web API project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42001182).

So in short:

1. To return views, use an MVC controller (inherited from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`)
2. Use a Web API controller (inherited from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`) when you want to return *data* to an application or browser.

Comment: Well is what I am doing, I have MVC Controller for returning Views and ApiControllers for getting and sending data. So is this ok? have both in same project?

Comment: No problem. They have their own data types, so will work in the same project. But keep in mind that each also has its own startup config, so see the above link. If you get stuck, it might not hurt to create an example project from the MVC5 template that includes Web API so you can compare differences in the configuration.