# Can I add an an MVC5 project to an existing (still running)ASPX project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an interesting situation where I need to quickly provide a feature to a customer, He said that he want to add a new module in the existing project(like One solution and multiple project).And He had a suggestion that he want that module in MVC5 framework.

Actually I'm new in that project. So any one to know the method to compine the project is a big help for me.
Actually I am new in stack overflow if any problem in the question please pardon me
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339475/how-to-add-mvc-to-existing-web-api-project

Comment: @JonathanWillcock here both are web applicatons

Comment: Have you tried following the answer given there?  Personally, when I have had to do this, I have always found it easier to create a new solution based on MVC and then add the older projects in.